# Cannot mount a iso file "failed to setup loop device"

Tags: loop-device

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and trying to moutn Matlab ISO using the following command:

```
sudo mount R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /mnt/cdrom -o loop
```

But terminal is responding back as:

```
mount: /mnt/cdrom: failed to setup loop device for R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso.
```

I am not sure as to what this means and how to take it forward.

Comment: Could you post output of the command: `file R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso`

Answer (score 6):

When I had this problem, I were trying to mount the iso image from a sshfs-mounted directory. After copying the iso image to the local filesystem, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Create `/mnt/cdrom` directory first:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
```

Afterwards mount the iso-image **with absolute image path**, for example `/home/user/R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso` instead of just `R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso`:

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/user/R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /mnt/cdrom
```

If the directory `/mnt/cdrom` exists, get more info about your iso-image:

```
file R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso
```

and try to mount with explicit filesystem type, for example:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /home/user/R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /mnt/cdrom
```

Additionally read [my answer at Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053579/847087), possibly your image has a boot sector, then mount it with `offset` option which should be calculated first.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer but it is giving me the same error: mount: /mnt/cdrom: failed to setup loop device for R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso.

Comment: @SayantanDatta Could you post output of the command: `file R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso`

Comment: R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'MATHWORKS_R2018A'

Comment: @SayantanDatta I have edited my answer. You have to add absolute path to image, for example: `/home/user/R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso` - not just `R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso`

Comment: So, I tried doing that and the error still persists - `mount: /mnt/cdrom: failed to setup loop device for R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso.`

Comment: @SayantanDatta Wait, I'm downloading the image now. I'll be back soon.

Comment: @SayantanDatta OK, just downloaded the image and successfully mounted it. I'm sure you typed wrong absolute path to the image. Check it carefully. Post output of the command: `ls -la <your-absolute-path-to-image>/R2018a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso` - replace <your-absolute-path-to-image> with your real path.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered a very similar problem. Fortunately, the answer of @user3049102 has lead me in the right direction and I have found [the explanation](https://kernelnewbies.kernelnewbies.narkive.com/aDPksZdF/help-fuse-and-loopback-not-working-together).

The problem was with the filesystem where the image file was stored (and it seems to me it could also have been your case).

My issue was with an ISO image on a prototype of a FUSE filesystem. I was not sure if I haven't implemented something or there was some other reason. In fact, the problem is quite simple and well explained but specific to exactly the FUSE-based filesystems (like the mentioned above `sshfs`, which current implementation is using FUSE). For security reasons, FUSE refuses accessing the files on the mounted filesystem to any other user besides the one who has mounted it. This behaviour can be changed by some FUSE mount options - this is explained on [FUSE's gihub](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) - see the section *"Security implications"*.

I guess this may be an issue also with some other filesystems - so if `sudo mount ... -o loop` fails with its generic error info, the first thing to do is checking if `root` can access the mounted image file. Then I'd also check if the filesystem where you store the image does not have some specific properties / limitations which may also cause that a file stored there cannot be configured as a loop device.

The simplest solution, as mentioned in the answer about `sshfs`, is to copy the file to some more "local" filesystem, or - at least in case of ISO images - use eg. [`fuseiso`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) to mount the image as the same user.