# "failed to setup loop device" when mounting an Ubuntu iso image on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, iso, loop-device

I downloaded an iso image of Ubuntu server, `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso`. Then I tried to mount this iso as a folder, using the usual command

```
mount ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso ./iso
```

, but I received error:

```
mount: ./iso: failed to setup loop device for .../ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso.
```

The same error shows up if I add `-o loop` or `-t iso9660`. I checked the thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634501/cant-mount-iso-file-as-loop-device-error-failed-to-setup-loop-device) but the answer (`lsmod | grep loop`, `modprobe loop`) does not work for me. How to solve this problem? I'm working on Ubuntu 20.10.

PS, must I have super user privilege to mount an iso file? I saw many questions mount iso with sudo but experiencing the same error. How to check if I have permissions to use `/dev/loop0`?

Comment: Take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462694/117549 and see if using `mount ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso "$PWD/iso"` works.